# Fetching textbox value at button click JQuery

Tags: jquery, button, onclick

i need to alert entered textbox value so i am doing it as follow.
Html code:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1"  class="cal" />
```

JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var get = $("#textbox").val();
   $("#calculate").click(function () {
     alert(get);

    });
});
```

At click,it always says undefined.Why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your id is `textbox1`, and you should get the value when clicked, or you just get the initial value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#calculate").click(function () {
       alert( $("#textbox1").val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
var get = $("#textbox").val();
```

To

```
var get = $("#textbox1").val();
```

So the `id` you are targetting matches your HTML, and put it inside your event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#calculate").click(function () {
       var get = $("#textbox1").val();
       alert(get);
    });
});
```

So you are getting the value **when you click the button** rather than on document load.